# Richtige Schreibweise "Vielen Dank im Vorraus"

Tags: spelling

Bei einer Googlesuche finde ich unterschiedliche Ergebnisse. Wie ist die korrekte Rechtschreibung?

Groß oder klein? Mit einem oder zwei R?

- Vielen Dank im Vorraus
- Vielen Dank im Voraus
- Vielen Dank im voraus
- Vielen Dank im vorraus

Comment: Keinesfalls mit zwei "r"!! Das Wort heißt "Voraus" und nicht "Vorraus", denn es hat nichts mit "raus" zu tun. "raus" ist eine Kurzform von "heraus", also müsste es sonst "Vorheraus" heißen, und das Wort gibt es nicht (wohl aber "Vorhinein"). Es kommt von "Vor" und "Aus". http://woerter.germanblogs.de/archive/2009/05/15/vorraus-oder-voraus-%E2%80%93-beliebter-fehler-breitet-sich-aus.htm

Comment: So gesehen wäre dann ein Fußballplatz auf seiner gesamten Fläche ein Vor-Aus. Solange der Ball die Kreidelinien nicht in vollem Umfang überquert hat, bleibt er im Spiel. Und unser Leben... das Vor-Nichts? Vor dem Vor-Nichts habe ich Angst, aber Nichts macht mir Eindruck. Denn wenn das Nichts nichtet, kann Nichts mehr als Sein. Etwa nicht? Wohl doch! Nach dem Vor-Nichts ist vor dem Nichts, dazwischen ist kein Platz mehr. Mut zur Lücke. Den Ball in die Gasse spielen. Dem Schippennmann von der Sense springen, oder umgekehrt. Nichts will mehr, Nichts geht mehr. Dahin, wo es weh tut.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die Schreibung No. 2 ist richtig.

Zitat [Duden](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/voraus):

> Besten Dank im Voraus: Voraus ist ein Adverb und wird deshalb
>   eigentlich kleingeschrieben. In der Fügung im Voraus ist es allerdings
>   substantiviert und wird deshalb großgeschrieben [Regel 81]

Comment: Ah, vielen Dank! Und eine gute Quelle zum nachschlagen

Answer (score 2):

Korrekte Schreibweise ist:

> Vielen Dank im Voraus

siehe auch:
http://www.schule-verstehen.de/Verstehen/Deutsch/Vielen-Dank-im-Voraus

Comment: Darf ich fragen wo der Anlaß für die 2. Antwort ist? Das ist doch nichts anderes als das, was in meiner Antwort schon steht, oder übersehe ich was?